# eclipse rcp startup issues

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I am having trouble running my eclipse RCP application. I am able to run it from eclipse, but when I make a exe file and try to run it, I see the following error. All the required plugins are there in the plugins folder. Anyone knows what the issue can be?

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-26 10:28:17.358

!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-26 10:28:17.359
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.6.2.3-10-19-85532e_.jar/ was not resolved.

!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2012-10-26 10:28:17.360

!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable_[1.2.0,2.0.0).

!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2012-10-26 10:28:17.360

!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.databinding.property_[1.2.0,2.0.0).

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-26 10:28:17.361

!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jface.databinding_1.4.0.I20100601-0800.jar/ was not resolved.

!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jface.databinding 2 0 2012-10-26 10:28:17.362

!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.databinding.property_[1.3.0,2.0.0).

!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jface.databinding 2 0 2012-10-26 10:28:17.363

!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable_[1.3.0,2.0.0).

!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2012-10-26 10:28:17.364

!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.core.databinding_1.3.100.I20100601-0800.jar/ was not resolved.

!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.databinding 2 0 2012-10-26 10:28:17.365

!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable_[1.3.0,2.0.0).

!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.databinding 2 0 2012-10-26 10:28:17.366

!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.core.databinding.property_[1.3.0,2.0.0).
```

Comment: fixed the config.ini file..and it worked...

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

1. Goto "Run->Run Configurations...".
2. Select the "Plugins" tab.
3. Click the "Add Required Plug In" button.

It's mentioned over [here](http://harikrushnav.blogspot.com/2013/04/eclipse-rcp-error-javalangruntimeexcept.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you synchronized it before creating the .exe in eclipse?